# How to find all throwable exceptions by a given code in python?

Tags: python, exception

I have a working codebase which contains instances of code like the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        foo()
        bar()
        kik()
        lol()
    except:
        sleep(0.05)
```

I now have to make changes to some or all of `foo`, `bar`, `kik`, and `lol`, and the too broad exception handling makes my life into hell as it is hard knowing what the original writer is catching and how not to break some use case.

How can I know all possible exceptions that this code can throw, so I can remedy this monstrosity, without making the currently working functionality break?

Thanks

Comment: Ultimately you can't since some code may very well invent a class on the fly and throw that.

Comment: @quamrana allright, then how would I tackle this? My code can't even catch syntax errors now

Comment: How do you think that you might `break some used case`?

Comment: Personally when I thought about this, I came to the conclusion that in the end such information can only come from documentation.

Comment: @quamrana well, if i take the liberty to assume that only exceptions A,B,C and D can arise from this code, and I miss E, that would very blatantly break the use case  where E is present.
There is no documentation. This is startup code. I find it hard to believe this is a unique problem in the world and that I am the first one to encounter something like this

Comment: You could still have a catch-all surrounding your specific `except` to at least log those you miss.